# Dagger 2 inject dependencies from multiple components

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have one problem.

In order to separate my components and keep the responsible for only specific part of application, I am using different components.

For example in my case I have **Application** component and **UserSessionComponent**. And I need to inject dependencies in the main Application class.

Here is code

```
@PerApplication 
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class,UtilsModule.class, DbModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    // Injection methods
    void inject(MainApplication mainApplication);
}
```

User **Session Component**

```
@PerUserSessionScope
@Component(dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class}, modules = {UserSessionCommonModule.class, UserSessionModule.class})
public interface UserSessionComponent {
    void inject(MainApplication mainApplication);
}
```

And in the **MainApplication** class I have the following dependency.

```
@Inject
protected UserSessionManager mUserSessionManager;
```

It throws an error while compiling that **ApplicationComponent** cannot provide required dependencies, that is obvious.

Injection is done in the following way

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent
            .builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .build();
    mApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    initUserSession();
}
```

So the question is how can I call the inject method on multiple components injecting in the same class.

Comment: Can you show how are you trying to inject `MainApplication` class?

Comment: @azizbekian sure I have just update my question

Comment: I see no updates.

Comment: You are building `ApplicationComponent` in your `MainApplication` class. That component has no knowledge of `UserSessionManager`, because presumably that dependency is being provided by `UserSessionCommonModule`, and `ApplicationComponent` doesn't include that module.

Comment: @azizbekian could you check this now. The problem is that it doesn't compile. I understand what causes the problem, but how to deal with this ?

Comment: `how to deal with this?` add `UserSessionCommonModule` in module list of  `MainComponent`.

Comment: @azizbekian I understand what causes the problem, but I want to keep my modules separated, is it possible to inject twice ?

Comment: What does it mean to inject twice? You can create `UserSessionComponent` and inject using that component instead of `MainComponent`.

Comment: @azizbekian The problem is that `ApplicationComponent` doesn't have the idea how to inject `UserManager`, that is clear. But I need to inject it a little bit later, after the `ApplicationComponent` injected all dependencies that it can resolve. After that I could create the UserSession component and call inject method to inject other dependencies in this case UserSessionManager